# What is this use of C# 'using' statement?

Tags: c#, keyword, using

What is this use of c# using statement?

```
namespace Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.DataProtection {
    using DataProtectionProviderDelegate = Func<string[], Tuple<Func<byte[], byte[]>, Func<byte[], byte[]>>>;
    using DataProtectionTuple = Tuple<Func<byte[], byte[]>, Func<byte[], byte[]>>;
```

[Taken from here](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/ac4f4f48a3c56221faa554995d8b8c1940b5f838/src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/DataProtection/MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider.cs)

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) using statement has two usages.

1. (directive) Import types into current files, either directly or by giving an alias
2. (statement) Ensure IDisposable objects are properly disposed.

But in this case, it's used to assign a delegate type. Can anyone please explain this usage, and provide a link a documentation?

Comment: Is it not the first one, giving things an alias?

Comment: please, remove the using system, this would make it more obvious that you want to know about the one inside the namespace, also who will win, the +1 comment  or the +1 answer?

Comment: removed the first using, thanks, and yes it has been the first one James. I thought only another namespace can be aliased, but a type can be aliased too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case the using statement is being used to alias a type, so yes point (1) you stated.

Later on in code rather than having to type:

```
var x = new  Tuple<Func<byte[], byte[]>, Func<byte[], byte[]>>(/* ... */);
```

You can write:

```
var x = new DataProtectionTuple(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Oh, Cool. in MSDN it says "To create an alias for a namespace or a type", didn't notice the 'type' part earlier. Thanks.